# GUI Freezing Issue When Sending SMS in C++/CLI Project

Tags: sms

In my program, I have an API SMS gateway but when I send an SMS by pressing the send button, it pauses my GUI.

I am using C++ in a Visual Studio CLR project (win forms).

How can I stop the freezing error?

Here is the code:

```
String^ sms(String^ recipient, String^ message) {
    String^ strSendData = String::Format(L"{{\"recipient\":\"{0}\",\"sender_id\":\"SendTest\",\"message\":\"{1}\"}}", recipient, message);

    WebClient^ sms = gcnew WebClient;
    sms->Headers->Add("accept", "application/json");
    sms->Headers->Add("authorization", "Bearer 1481|sm95wmZwh0n1VP75cTobJQfnaH5watlRZ3DnPkY");
    sms->Headers->Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
    sms->Headers->Add("content-type", "application/json");

    try {
        array<Byte>^ responseData = sms->UploadData("https://sms.send.lk/api/v3/sms/send", "POST", Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(strSendData));
        String^ responseString = Encoding::UTF8->GetString(responseData);
        return responseString;
    }
    catch (WebException^ ex) {
        // Handle exception (if any) here
        //MessageBox::Show(ex->Message, "Error");
        return "Error: " + ex->Message;
    }
}
```